# My javaScript functions are not working, can someone direct me to why they don't work. thanks

Tags: javascript, function

I cannot get my functions to work. i have labeled all my functions:

```js
//This function validates the checkboxes:
// I am trying to use this function to validate checkboxes:
function checkCheckBoxes() {
  if (theForm.dinner.checked == false) {
    alert('You did not select a dish!');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

//this funciton validates the quantity entered to be a number:
//I am trying to use this function to make sure the character they input in the quantity box is a number:
function checkForNumber(fieldValue) {
  var numberCheck = isNan(fieldValue);
  if (numbercheck == true) {
    window.alert("You must enter a numeric value!");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

// This function is supposed to ask the user to make sure they want to hit submit or reset:
//this function is to ask the user if they really want to submit the form or if they really want to reset the form:
function confirmSubmit() {
  var submitForm = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the form?');
  if (submitForm == true)
    return true;
  return false;
}

function confirmReset() {
  var resetForm = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the form?');
  if (resetForm == true)
    return true;
  return false;
}

//this function is used to validate the checkboxes:
function submitForm() {
  var dinner = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (document.forms[0].dinner[i].checked == true) {
      dinner = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (dinner == false) {
    window.alert('You must select at least one dish.');
    return dinner;
  } else
    return dinner;
}


// I am trying to calculate the price once they make a selection in checkboxes:

//this function calculates the price:
function sumOfCheckedBoxes() {
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.form[0].dinner.length; i++) {
    if (document.form[0].dinner[i].checked) {
      total = total + document.form[0].dinner[i].value * 1;
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count == 1) {
    alert("Your amount for the selcected dish is " + total);
  } else if (count > 1) {
    alert("The total of the " + count + "checkboxes you have checked is" + total);
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
}
label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return checkCheckboxes() && confirmSubmit()" onreset="return confirmReset();">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Menu order form</legend>
    <table>
      <caption>
        <h3>Dinner Menu</h3>
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label for="dish">Dish
              <br>
            </label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label for="picture">Picture</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <label for="price">Price</label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <label for="choose">
              <p><strong>Make a selection:</strong>
              </p>
            </label>
            <br />
            <label for="steak">
              <input type="checkBox" id="tSteak" name="dinner" value="19.99" onsubmit="sumOfCheckedBoxes()" />Tuscan Steak</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="quantity">
              Quantity
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="steak" id="plate1" onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="img">
              <img src="steak.jpg" alt="steak" id="steak">
              <br />
            </label>
            <label for="comments">
              Comments:
              <textarea name="cm" cols="20" rows="2">How would you like your steak cooked?</textarea>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="price">$19.99</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />
            <label for="chicken">
              <input type="checkBox" id="tChicken" name="dinner" value="13.99" onsubmit="sumOfCheckedBoxes()" />Tuscan Chicken</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="quantity">Quantity
              <br />
              </quantity>
              <input type="text" name="chicken" id="plate2" onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="grilledchicken.jpg" alt="chicken" id="chicken">
            <br />Comments:
            <textarea name="cm" cols="20" rows="2">Enter special instructions</textarea>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="price">$13.99</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />
            <label for="pasta">
              <input type="checkBox" id="iPasta" name="dinner" value="12.99" onsubmit="sumOfCheckedBoxes()" />Sun Dried Pasta</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="quantity">
              Quantity
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="pasta" id="plate3" onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="sundriedpasta.jpg" alt="pasta" id="pasta">
            <br />Comments:
            <textarea name="cm" cols="20" rows="2">Enter special instructions</textarea>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="price">$12.99</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />
            <label for="rigatonni">
              <input type="checkBox" id="iRigatonni" name="dinner" value="9.99" onsubmit="sumOfCheckedBoxes()" />Rigatonni</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="quantity">
              Quantity
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="rigatonni" id="plate4" onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="rigatonni.jpg" alt="rigatonni" id="rigatonni">
            <br />Comments:
            <textarea name="cm" cols="20" rows="2">Enter special instructions</textarea>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="price">$15.99</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />
            <label for="ensalada">
              <input type="checkBox" id="iEnsalada" name="dinner" value="yes" onsubmit="sumOfCheckedBoxes()" />Italian Ensalada</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="quantity">Quantity
              <br />
              <input type="text" name="ensalada" id="plate5" onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="ensalada.jpg" alt="ensalada" id="ensalada">
            <br />Comments:
            <textarea name="cm" cols="20" rows="2">Enter special instructions</textarea>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="price">$9.99</label>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>


  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="send my order!">
  <input type="reset">
</form>



<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Stay Connected!</legend>

    <h3>Subscribe to our Newsletter!</h3>
    e-mail:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="sign me up!">
    <input type="reset">
  </fieldset>
</div>

<p>
  <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
    <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: All I'm seeing here is a lot of unformatted code and no description of a problem.  We can't tell you how to fix it if you won't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit doesn't work on input fields. You should run your checks onsubmit of the form - or - onblur of the input element.